# text align center together with google icons

Tags: css, icons, material-design

I have google icon with texts. I need to center align my text so that it look good with icon. I tried css vertical align and did not work. Can any one help me align center my texts.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="vertical-align: middle">yyyy<i class='material-icons'>clear</i>yyyy</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare the `vertical-align` property to the icon instead (since it is already `display: inline-block`), e.g:

```
<i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: middle">clear</i>
```

Or wrap the text in *inline* elements you can style to align *vertically* with the icon,e.g:

```
<span style="vertical-align: top">yyyy</span><i class="material-icons">clear</i><span style="vertical-align: top">yyyy</span>
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>yyyy<i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: middle">clear</i>yyyy</p>
    <p><span style="vertical-align: top">yyyy</span><i class="material-icons">clear</i><span style="vertical-align: top">yyyy</span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```